# Powershell: how to use xpath to filter by attribute and content at the same time?

Tags: xml, powershell, select, xpath

I have this script:

```
function f3
{
[xml]$xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Book>
  <projects>
    <project name="Book1" date="2009-01-20">
      <editions>
        <edition language="English">Novel_1</edition>
        <edition language="English">my.Book1.com</edition>
        <edition language="German">Ge.Book1.Com</edition>
        <edition language="French">Fr.Book1.com</edition>
        <edition language="Polish">Pl.Book1.com</edition>
        <edition language="English">Novel_2</edition>
        <edition language="English">FairyTale</edition>
      </editions>
    </project>
  </projects>
</Book>
"@

$xml.SelectNodes("/Book/projects/editions")
}
f3
```

I wish to select "language=English", with content either contains "Novel" or equals "FairyTale", so my expected output is:

```
Novel_1
Novel_2
FairyTale
```

So how can I change my "SelectNodes" statement?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In xpath, you can combine multiple boolean values using standard boolean operators like `or` and `and` :

```
/Book/*/*/*/edition[@language='English' and (.='FairyTale' or contains(.,'Novel'))]
```

alternatively, separating `and` operands into two predicates (`[]`) :

```
/Book/*/*/*/edition[@language='English'][.='FairyTale' or contains(.,'Novel')]
```

For this case, you may also want to consider using `starts-with()` function instead of `contains()` to be more precise.

<sub>side note : `*` is just my way to shorten the xpath expression to fit in one line without having to reduce efficeincy (f.e using `//` axis like `/Book//edition`), you are fine to use the actual element names in place of `*`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The solution below updates the xpath to the editions element, then applies the where to filter as you requested.

```
$xml.SelectNodes("/Book/projects/project/editions/edition") `
    | Where-Object { $_.language -eq "English" } `
    | Where-Object { $_."#text" -like "*novel*" -or $_."#text" -eq "FairyTale" } `
    | Format-Table @{Expression={$_."#text"};Label="Novel"}
```